# Ignore or sidestep a name error

Tags: python, string, list, set, jinja2

I feel like I'm turning a molehill into a mountain here but I can't think of or don't know of a better way to do this.

In short, **I have** a list of lists that looks like:

`[ [4.54323, 5.4325], [7.235, 3.67543], [9.342543, 1.65323] ]`

And **I need** a list that looks like the following:

`[ {lat: 4.54323, lng: 5.4325}, {lat: 7.235, lng: 3.67543}, {lat: 9.342543, lng: 1.65323} ]`

I've done some things I'm not proud of and have ended up with:

`[ '{lat: 4.54323, lng: 5.4325}', '{lat: 7.235, lng: 3.67543}', '{lat: 9.342543, lng: 1.65323}' ]`

Yup, some string manipulation and now I'm *stuck* with a list of strings. I then tried to evaluate each element in said list but got a `NameError: name 'lat' is not defined.` unsurprisingly.

So this more of a multi-part question. Is there a way to get what I want without turning elements into strings and replacing characters? Or alternatively, can I evaluate or turn these strings into whatever data type they should be (I think sets). This variable is only going to be sent to a HTML file to replace a variable by using Jinja. So it doesn't really need to be understood by python, (I'm using 2.7.x).

**EDIT:** This is the method I'm working with, I'm actively trying not to share that much code because of work reasons, sorry. There's also a lot of different attempts been made in the lifetime of the method. So some lines may look weird.

```
evalledCoords = []

def make_points(coords):
if(coords):
    for x in range(0, len(coords)):
        # remove first element, not needed.
        coords[x].pop(0)
        coords[x] = str(coords[x]).replace("[", "{lat: ").replace(",", ", lng:").replace("]", "}")
        # See outputs
        print '\n', coords[x]
        print 'evalled coords', evalledCoords.append(eval(coords[x]))
return coords
```

Comment: Show your latest code please so the reader can have a better understanding of where you are making your mistake.

Comment: Just added some relevant code in the edit. I can't share anything I want unfortunately. In the bit where I say '...this is what I've ended up with' they are strings. In the example given there are 3 strings in that 1 list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the provided data structures and what expected output you are looking to achieve, this can be done through a simple loop over your existing data structure and creating a new list of dictionaries:

```
coords = [ [4.54323, 5.4325], [7.235, 3.67543], [9.342543, 1.65323] ]

new_list = []
for data in coords:
    new_list.append({
        'lat': data[0],
        'lng': data[1]
    })

print(new_list)
# [{'lng': 5.4325, 'lat': 4.54323}, {'lng': 3.67543, 'lat': 7.235}, {'lng': 1.65323, 'lat': 9.342543}]
```

Or, simply as a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [{'lat': d[0], 'lng': d[1]} for d in coords]

print(new_list)
# [{'lng': 5.4325, 'lat': 4.54323}, {'lng': 3.67543, 'lat': 7.235}, {'lng': 1.65323, 'lat': 9.342543}]
```

Comment: You take the biscuit sir. Many thanks. The simple list comprehension outside the for loop solved it for me people of the future.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using dictionaries, consider using namedtuples to store your position data. They use less RAM, and the components can be accessed either by index or as attributes. Since namedtuples are a type of tuple they are immutable, but it generally make sense for (latitude, longitude) info of a place to be stored in an immutable data structure. :)

Here's a short demo.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Pos = namedtuple('Pos', ('lat', 'lng'))

a = Pos(30, 150)
print(a)
print(a[0], a.lng)

coords = [ 
    [4.54323, 5.4325],
    [7.235, 3.67543],
    [9.342543, 1.65323],
]

locations = [Pos(*u) for u in coords]
print(locations)
```

**output**

```
Pos(lat=30, lng=150)
30 150
[Pos(lat=4.54323, lng=5.4325), Pos(lat=7.235, lng=3.67543), Pos(lat=9.342543, lng=1.65323)]
```

Comment: Ah yes! I never give namedtuple enough attention. Good call!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve "i have this and i want this" it can simply be done with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

```
>>> a = [ [4.54323, 5.4325], [7.235, 3.67543], [9.342543, 1.65323] ]
>>> map(lambda x: {'lat': x[0], 'lng': x[1]}, a)
[{'lat': 4.54323, 'lng': 5.4325}, {'lat': 7.235, 'lng': 3.67543}, {'lat': 9.342543, 'lng': 1.65323}]
```

**UPDATE**

To make your function to work

```
def make_points(coords):
    return map(lambda x: {'lat': x[0], 'lng': x[1]}, coords)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm bad at formatting in comments. I have a screenshot showing your idea in my method. Nothing has changed though, what am I doing wrong?
http://imgur.com/a/UlJJ5

Comment: @Shmink i've updated the question with function that do what you want.